# Can i get other App's opening closing call backs in my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ios8, ipc

I want to build an app which will get the notification's for open close events of other apps on device, Is it possible? 
I googled and came across one suggestion from Quora [How can an iOS app get the list of all the other apps installed on the device?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-an-iOS-app-get-the-list-of-all-the-other-apps-installed-on-the-device)  Which gives the list only , and that is not with real app name it gives the process name only,

I want to get notify about the opening and closing of other applications in my iOS device from my application.

suppose my app name is 'getNotify' then it will receive the notification if i opens the facebook in my deivce, or twitter in my device or any other app in my device.

Comment: ... and if you read the iOS documentation you'll see that correctly implemented apps permit themselves to be killed at any time, relaunching in the same state. So `sysctl` doesn't even return the list of things a user thinks is running. Just the current contents of the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it. You are sandboxed; that is part of the point of iOS. And if another app is launching, your app, by definition, is not running and cannot receive any notifications.